# While running the php artisan migrate or any serve command then I am getting this error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

When I try to run the php artisan migrate command then, I got

During inheritance of ArrayAccess: Uncaught ErrorException: Return type of Illuminate\Support\Collection::offsetExists($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in E:\hrms\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Collections\Collection.php:1459

full stack trace

```
#0 E:\hrms\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Collections\Collection.php(13): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(8192, 'Return 
type of ...', 'E:\\hrms\\vendor\\...', 1459)
#1 E:\hrms\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php(571): include('E:\\hrms\\vendor\\...')
#2 E:\hrms\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php(428): Composer\Autoload\includeFile('E:\\hrms\\vendor\\...')
#3 E:\hrms\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Collections\helpers.php(15): Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass('Illuminate\\Supp...')
#4 E:\hrms\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest.php(130): collect(Array)
#5 E:\hrms\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest.php(106): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->build()
#6 E:\hrms\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest.php(89): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->getManifest()
#7 E:\hrms\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest.php(78): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->config('aliases')
#8 E:\hrms\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterFacades.php(26): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->aliases()
#9 E:\hrms\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(237): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterFacades->bootstrap(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application))
#10 E:\hrms\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php(310): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootstrapWith(Array)
#11 E:\hrms\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php(127): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->bootstrap()
#12 E:\hrms\artisan(37): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#13 {main} in E:\hrms\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Collections\Collection.php on line 13
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "Illuminate\Support\Collection" not found in E:\hrms\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Collections\helpers.php:15Stack trace:
#0 E:\hrms\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Traits\ReflectsClosures.php(24): collect(Array)
#1 E:\hrms\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Traits\ReflectsClosures.php(44): Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\ReportableHandler->closureParameterTypes(Object(Closure))
#2 E:\hrms\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\ReportableHandler.php(62): Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\ReportableHandler->firstClosureParameterType(Object(Closure))
#3 E:\hrms\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler.php(234): Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\ReportableHandler->handles(Object(Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError))
#4 E:\hrms\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions.php(88): Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler->report(Object(Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError))
#5 E:\hrms\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions.php(130): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleException(Object(Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError))
#6 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleShutdown()
#7 {main}
  thrown in E:\hrms\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Collections\helpers.php on line 15
```

Can you please help me out in this. I tried to find it on everywhere but I was not able to find the exact solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I ran `composer update` and that solved the problem.